# rlt8814AU driver was working...suddenly stopped 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, asus, realtek-wireless

I picked up this external asus ac68 usb wireless card a while back and was able to get it working by entering this into the terminal...

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/hanipouspilot/rtl8814AU.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814AU
sudo dkms install rtl8814AU/4.3.21
```

It was working for a few weeks until  my system stopped seeing the card.

I tried to reinstall and this is what comes up when I try this method again

```
About to run dkms install steps...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/src/rtl8814AU-4.3.21’: File exists
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8814AU-4.3.21
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make'........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814AU: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-32-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/make.log for more information.
```

I've tried trying to reinstall the rtl8814au driver with various other methods found on askubuntu to no avail. I'm pretty new with command line script.

I know the card still works because I got it working on another distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel is too new to work with that source code, check `dkms status` to see what your old kernel was as I would think it is 4.10.0-?

What you can do is reboot and hold the SHIFT key until the Grub Menu appears and scroll down to Advanced Options, press enter and you should see a new menu, scroll down to the first entry for an older kernel and press enter.  Then in terminal

```
cd Desktop
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8814AU.git
```

Reboot and let it boot into the 4.13 kernel automatically, then in terminal

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8814AU/4.3.21 -k $(uname -r)
sudo dkms uninstall rtl8814AU/4.3.21
sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8814AU-4.3.21
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU
cd Desktop
sudo dkms add rtl8814AU
sudo dkms install rtl8814AU/1.0
```

Reboot and let it use the 4.13 kernel

Comment: Holy noodle look at that the card lives! Does the rm -r script remove directories and their contents, ensuring that when the new kernel is added there isn't an existing directory of the same name?

Comment: The rm -r commands are to make sure the old source code is gone for when newer 4.13 kernels are installed.   You will likely need newer source code in August when you will likely be upgraded to the 4.15 kernel unless that kernel has support for rtl8814au devices in tree

Comment: Not a problem, I have a similar rtl8814au device that I just got working in Ubuntu 17.10 with the 4.13 kernel